# Does deleting the schedule of a recipe affect other recipes?

Tags: scheduled-job, tableau-crm, einstein-analytics-dashboards, dataflow

I've a TCRM/EA Dashboard that runs on three recipes say `A`, `B` and `C`. There are connections b/w the recipes as well.

- Recipe `A` is scheduled to run hourly.
- Recipe `B` and `C` are scheduled to run after recipe `A` finishes (After Event)
- There are two widgets in the dashboard that use lenses (2 lenses, one for each) from recipe `C`.

If I remove the schedule for recipe `C`, will it affect the entire dashboard or just the two widget/lenses that uses the recipe?

What are the impacts of removing the schedule? Will removing the schedule result only in obsolete data (the dashboard would still serve its purpose, other than the two widgets) or are there any other impacts?